# how to pass multiple arguments to onSuccess function in Prototype?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, call

I am a beginner in using Prototype library. I want to know how we can pass multiple arguments to onSuccess/onFailure function in Prototype?
For example:-

```
new Ajax.Request('testurl',{
        method: 'post',
        parameters: {param1:"A", param2:"B", param3:"C"},
        onSuccess: fnSccs,
        onFailure: fnFail
        })
```

In my success function fnSccs:-

```
function fnSccs(response)
{
    alert(response.responseText);
}
```

I want to pass a new argument to fnSccs function. How is that possible. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could wrap your success function into another one that recieves the desired parameter, and returns your old function back:

```
new Ajax.Request('testurl',{
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {param1:"A", param2:"B", param3:"C"},
                onSuccess: mySuccess('myValue1', 'myValue2'),
                onFailure: fnFail
                })

function mySuccess(param1, param2){
  return function(response){ // Your old success function
    alert(param1);  // The parameter still accessible here
    alert(param2);
    alert(response);
  }
}
```

What happens is that when you call `mySuccess(...)` your old function is returned, but you still have access to the parameters because the variables remain allocated on the outer [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml).

You can check the running snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/oxixu/edit).

Comment: Why would you create an function when a simple closure would have done the trick? onSucess : function(response){ myNextStep(response, 'a', 'b'); }

Comment: is mySuccess() not executed here on the moment that you create the second argument in new Ajax.Request(), thus long before the request is send? To me it seems that to the key 'onSuccess' merely the return value of mySuccess is assigned, which is undefined...