# Jquery - (this) not defined in success block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use Jquery quite a bit and I must be missing something simple here.  I am trying to access this in the success block of this ajax call, but I get a `Reference Error: that is not defined` inside the success block.  Here is the code:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.row', function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        var id = $row.parent().data().scout;
        var requirement_id = $row.data().req;
        var req = $.ajax({
          url: '/scouts/' + id + '/reqs',
          data: {requirement_id: requirement_id },
          type: 'PUT'
        });
        var success = function() {
          // that not defined
          $row;
        };
        req.done(success);
      });
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have other `that` elsewhere ? That's the problem with this bad convention...

Comment: Whatever you have shared looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/92xMh/1/

Comment: Positive.  I also do not have access to `id` or `requirement_id`.  I also tried adding the success block as a field in the `.ajax` hash, but it still gave me the same result.

Comment: in normal circumstances I prefer using $.proxy() to pass a custom context instead of using a closure variable

Comment: Is your `success handler` an inner function of the `onclick handler`, or you're just calling it?

Comment: @jhamm: Is that the exact code from which you are getting the error? If not, please post the actual code. Maybe you have some mismatched parenthesis that close the function before you expect, and your `success` is defined outside the scope.

Comment: I am just calling it.  This code works fine in the jsfiddle from `Arun` above.  This is really weird.  I don't understand.

Comment: I copied and pasted it right out of Sublime Text to SO.  I haven't changed anything or added anything.

Comment: To be sure you don't reuse the `that` variable, try giving it a meaningful name (for example `$row`).

Comment: I named it `$row` and had the same problem. There is a fiddle above that shows this code working.

Comment: @jhamm: Did you do a `var that` inside the `success` function? The code you posted is working. Are you sure your browser executed exactly that one (caching issues or something)? Step through it with the debugger and tell us about the scope in the handler.

Comment: I changed the code to get rid of the `that` and gave it a name to make it more clear.  This is the exact code.  I do not declare a `var` in the success function.  I am able to see `$row` at every point other than inside the `success` block.

Comment: @jhamm : Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244697/extra-parameter-for-jquerys-ajax-success-function) will help you

Comment: @jhamm could you please explain what you are tring to do???

Comment: I am just trying to update the row when the success function come back.  There must be a major misunderstanding on my part or a shadowing problem that is being obscure to me.  I don't want to waste any more of your guys time.

Comment: @jhamm: Can you make a public demo and link it here?